# How to get row number in xlrd and save it into a variable

Tags: python, xlrd

I am trying to iterate over first column and look for specific value.
If the row contains that specific value I want to get the row number and save it into a variable.

here is the code:

```
rows_exceptions_file = []

for cell in sheet2.col(0):
    if cell.value == "test01":
        rows_exceptions_file.append(cell.rowx)
```

Exception that I am getting is : 'Cell' object has no attribute 'rowx'

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: it is not working. I get an error of : 'Cell' object has no attribute 'rowx'

Comment: Ah now I get it. Have you had a look into `enumerate`?

Comment: To be honest I haven't! Do you have any idea how to do it? Thanks

Comment: `rowx` is just the name of the parameter passed to cell access functions, it's not attribute of one. This makes sense because a cell object shouldn't care what it's location is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rows are numbered like `0, 1,..` you can just use `enumerate` like this:

```
for i, cell in enumerate(sheet2.col(0)):
    if cell.value == "test01":
        rows_exceptions_file.append(i)
```

`enumerate` returns the number of the iteration and the element, which makes it a perfect fit for this task, I think.

EDIT: `enumerate` also takes a `start`-argument, if you want to start the numeration from anything else then `0`:

```
enumerate(sheet2.col(0), start=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I am afraid this won't work because I want to return the actual number of the row in excel where that specific data is populated. Enumerate would just return the list of numbers but not the actual row of the data. Let's say that the data that I am looking for is in row 5, 7 and 10 , enumerate would return, if I am not mistaken, 1,2,3 ! Do you maybe have some other suggestions?

Comment: But you do loop through every row, right? It looks like that and in that case, this solution should give the right numbers. Please try and see if it works. If it doesn't, I would be surprised, but maybe we can find a different approach. If it works, I might have to add an explanation

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and let you know! Cheers

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I just had to add + 1 to every number in the list because enumerate starts from 0 and my rows start from 1.